# Magento Success Message Issue when add product it will displays on different page

Tags: product, magento-2.1, addtocart, messages

Magento Success Message Issue when add product it will displays on different page like when we go to contact page it will display on that page means it will not display on product page and it display on another page.
[image]

Please Provide me hints for to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

Are you using some CDN? 
Which cache you are using? 
Generally Magento session message will print on **next Http request** i.e like if you are at product detail page and do add to cart then you redirect user again to product detail then it will show on product detail if it will hit the server. If it will be from some cache or server then message will only show when next http request hit the server.

Comment: Thanks Aman For Reply, I don't know what is CDN but i am installing three modules namely Magefan Blog, Solwin Instagram And Peec Facebook. So it is affect? And only for prduct the message will display on next url.I am adding product from product view page like product view page.

Comment: So after adding product from product view page where users are redirecting?

Comment: No user isnot redirecting.If i am adding product it added in minicart but the problem is the success message should not display for that page. It is display to next URL like any Url u r searching.

Comment: I think either you can redirect user to same page after adding product to cart or you can use thislink to remove that success message :

[remove success message](http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/removing-the-added-to-your-shopping-cart-message-in-magento/)

Comment: No i am not using any link to remove success message. I am not touch any file of the Message.This issue only for add product any other working right.

Comment: In this case yes its only for add to cart. But just take note that message session message  always print on next http request.

Comment: Ok then what can i do for this?

Comment: I think this link will help you please have a look 

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5301

Comment: But This link doesnot solve my problem. I am also refer first to put the question in stackexchange

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54063/discussion-between-aman-and-moin-malek).